# Error installing Plotly package - mismatch between tag

Tags: r, plotly, install.packages

Having trouble installing the plotly package, which I'd like to use for some interactive plots.
I'm getting the following error:

THANKS in advance for any help.

```
package ‘plotly’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot delete reparse point 'C:\Users\XXX\OneDrive - XXX\R\win-library\4.0/plotly/help', reason 'There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point'
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘plotly’
Warning in install.packages :
  restored ‘plotly’
The downloaded binary packages are in
XXX
```

getRversion() --> [1] ‘4.0.2’
sessionInfo() --> R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Comment: Close R (and RStudio), restart R without an `.Rdata` file (i.e., not in a project), and try again. While it might not be the cause of this issue, there are reasons why a package being used will not be upgraded "in-place".

Comment: Thanks. Tried that, both in Rstudio and R, but still gettting the error message:
Warning messages:

1: In unlink(instPath, recursive = TRUE, force = TRUE) :
  cannot delete reparse point 'C:\Users\xxx\OneDrive - XXX\R\win-library\4.0/plotly/help', reason 'There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point'
2: In unlink(instPath, recursive = TRUE) :
  cannot delete reparse point 'C:\Users\xxx\XXX\R\win-library\4.0/plotly/help', reason 'There is a mismatch between the tag specified in the request and the tag present in the reparse point'